# Comparing Data from two columns in CSV files

Tags: python

Appreciate any help on this one. I have 7 CSV files (all the same format) that that I have concatenated into one frame. My goal here is to compare two columns from the CSV's and find out how many times the word "Done" from the "Ran" column show up on each Date from the "Date" column. So far this is what I have written:

```
path = r'C:\Users\rock\Desktop\workspace\MTS_subs'          
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

counter = frame['Ran'].value_counts()
date_counter = frame['Date'].value_counts()


print(counter, date_counter)
```

this prints out the following:

```
Active    1739
Done       840
Name: Ran, dtype: int64 18/06/2020    402
19/06/2020    300
17/06/2020    266
25/06/2020    264
22/06/2020    224
16/06/2020    214
23/06/2020    208
24/06/2020    208
26/06/2020    184
15/06/2020    180
21/06/2020     76
14/06/2020     46
20/06/2020      4
13/06/2020      3
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

So in all 7 CSVs, the word "Done" appears 840 times but I would like to find out how many times "Done" appears on each of those dates.

I've been scratching my head at this one for sometime. Any help or input is very much appreciated.

[image: CSV Image]

Comment: I would assume it'd involve a function or method called `filter` to filter only the rows that have `row["Ran"] == "Done"` then do `df['Date'].value_counts()` on that but I'm not familiar with the specific syntax of pandas to give working example.

Comment: Do you have an example of one of the CSV files?

Comment: Added a snip of one of the CSV's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(frame['Ran'] == 'Done').groupby(frame['Date']).sum()` should do the trick. Below is an example that simulates the screenshot that was posted.

```py
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame({
...     'Date': ['13/06/2020']*3 + ['15/06/2020']*2 + ['14/06/2020']*12,
...     'Ran': ['Done']*17
... })
>>> frame
          Date   Ran
0   13/06/2020  Done
1   13/06/2020  Done
2   13/06/2020  Done
3   15/06/2020  Done
4   15/06/2020  Done
5   14/06/2020  Done
6   14/06/2020  Done
7   14/06/2020  Done
8   14/06/2020  Done
9   14/06/2020  Done
10  14/06/2020  Done
11  14/06/2020  Done
12  14/06/2020  Done
13  14/06/2020  Done
14  14/06/2020  Done
15  14/06/2020  Done
16  14/06/2020  Done
>>> (frame['Ran'] == 'Done').groupby(frame['Date']).sum()
Date
13/06/2020     3.0
14/06/2020    12.0
15/06/2020     2.0
Name: Ran, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hmm not having much luck with this line.

Comment: What do you mean? Throwing an error, or not getting the right result?

Comment: Yes I got it to work now, might of been a copy and paste error. Thanks so much for your help. This is amazing!